# WF4 services and Bookmarks

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Do bookmarks come into play with WF4 services? It doesn't seem to me that they would. For example a workflow service could have several receive and sendreply activities and state would be persisted after sendreplies.

If I understand things correctly, the correct workflow instance would be loaded back into memory upon receiving a message by using correlation.

Is all of this right?

Answer (score 3):

Bookmarks are very much a part of workflow services. In fact under the hood a Receive or a ReceiveReply activity uses a bookmark to pause execution until the expected message is received.

You are correct in assuming that message correlation is used by the WF runtime to find the correct workflow instance to process a WCF request. And if the WorkflowServiceHost is configured to use an instance store and persist workflows there reloading it back into memory is part of the process.

Comment: Thanks, Maurice. What I was really trying to find out is whether the developer needs to manage bookmarks or not when using WF services. If the receive activities do this for you, then it sounds like no.

Comment: With a Receive activity the runtime will take care of things for you. Obviously you are responsible for managing your own bookmarks and reloading workflows & resuming the bookmarks when appropriate